# Ember-Router: create route dynamically

Tags: dynamic, ember.js, state, ember-router

I am trying to dynamically create a route to my router. I know there is serialize for doing this, but it appears to only accept a finite amount of parameters. For example, I need to be able to build a route that could be `/:a` or `/:a/:b/:c`.

My question is, is there a way to get what the original path request was?

I will need to:

- get the original path
- pause the router so an ajax call can be made to retrieve path info.
- request from the server the path and return the module if it exists
  (I have that much set up).
- If path exists, create the route and move the application into that
  state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the requested location via the router's location property.
You could then split the returned string and access the different parameters.

```
locationString = App.router.get('location.location.hash')
// something like "/1/2"
params = locationString.split(/\//)
param1 = params[1] // => "1"
param2 = params[2] // => "2"
```